# How to install SQL Server 2012 on Windows 10

Tags: sql-server-2012

Currently this has been a huge pain for me. 
I have a fresh Windows 10 VM. I Installed SQL Server 2012. I open up the SQL Server Studio 2012, and there is no server name that I can choose from in the "Connect to Server" dialog box that shows up.

Additional Context:
10.0.2100.60 is the sql server version
4.0 is the .net framework

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I was doing was installing just the management studio, and not the sql server service, which is why it wasn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

put the computer name\service name, like TOOLS-PC\SQLEXPRESS2012 
if instance on computer only one - can put only computer name 
or just - (local)

name of server instance You can check in service list or by run SQL Configuration Manager

Comment: The only sql related service that is running on my computer is named
"SQL Server VSS Writer". There is no SQLEXPRESS2012...

Comment: so - are You sure in this case, about successful install SQL Server? at least MUST be - SQL Server, can be - SQL Server Agent (if not express), SQL Server Browser. But first - MUST be